# How to build Lucene Query x AND (y OR z)

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to create an query for Lucene to search like below

word:"searched_word" AND (category:0 OR category:1)

what means searched_word must be in word field and category field is 0 or 1.

word field is normal Field type
category field is NumericField type

```
    BooleanQuery mainQuery = new BooleanQuery();

    Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("category", NumericUtils.IntToPrefixCoded(0)));
    Query query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("category", NumericUtils.IntToPrefixCoded(1));

    Query queryTerm= new TermQuery(new Term("word", searchedWord));


    mainQuery.Add(queryTerm, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

    BooleanQuery innerOrQuery = new BooleanQuery();

    //How do i add them as OR and as AND to mainQuery
    innerOrQuery.Add(querySingleDirection, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    innerOrQuery.Add(queryBothDirection, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
     mainQuery.Add(innerOrQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    TopDocs topDocs = _indexSearcher.Search(mainQuery, Settings.Current.MaximumTopScoreCount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Query queryTerm = new TermQuery(new Term("word", searchedWord));
Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("category", NumericUtils.IntToPrefixCoded(0)));
Query query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("category", NumericUtils.IntToPrefixCoded(1));

BooleanQuery innerOrQuery = new BooleanQuery();
innerOrQuery.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
innerOrQuery.Add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

BooleanQuery mainQuery = new BooleanQuery();
mainQuery.Add(queryTerm, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
mainQuery.Add(innerOrQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

TopDocs topDocs = _indexSearcher.Search(mainQuery, Settings.Current.MaximumTopScoreCount);
```

Comment: Hi. Can you please look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906689/filter-not-working-with-text-values-lucene-3-0-3 . Going crazy over it.